# Python & Google Sheets - Look for Element in Row 5 and Column 3

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I want to do something like that

```py
sheet.row_values(5).col_values(3)
```

But that won't work, I only found something like that

```py
sheet.col_values(3)
```

but this would give me every Item of the Column 3, but I want the Item in Row 5 and Column 3. Is something like that possible?
Thanks.

Edit: At the end it should look like that:

```py
Item = sheet.row_values(5).col_values(3)
if not Item:
    sheet.insert(row, 5, col, 3, 'text') # That won't work too, I would be happy if someone could help me with that too
```

Comment: do it in two steps, first get every item in the column and then get row 5 from that list.

Comment: So I could do something like that, but I want something else to happen if row 5 is nothing, but if I would do it like that and get the 5. Item of the list something else would come if the 5. Item is nothing, I will update the Thread now to explain it a little bit more

Comment: Updated it @Ricardo I hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I somehow did it.
Heres the code (This Script just checks the HWID):

```
    hwids = sheet.cell(i, 3)
    if str(hwids) == f'<Cell R{i}C3 \'\'>':
        sheet.update_cell(i, 3, hwid)
    hwidd = f'<Cell R{i}C3 \'{hwid}\'>'
    hwids = sheet.cell(i, 3)
    if str(hwidd) == str(hwids):
        print('yay, it's right!')
```

You need that <Cell R{i}C3 ''> because sheet.cell is a Cell and it won't work if you don't do that.
The {i} is the row number, I got that with the Username check, if you want that too just go to my last question and you will see the answer from me.
I hope I could help someone that maybe wanted to do the same!